# Commutativity and Associativity of Poincare Transformations

Tags: inertial-frames, group-theory, poincare-symmetry

Commutativity and Associativity of Poincare Transformations:

For commutativity I showed that $2$ successive transformations does not commute with the same transformations reversed.

$$(Λ_2 Λ_1, Λ_2 a_1 + a_2)$$ does not commute with $$(Λ_1 Λ_2, Λ_1 a_2 + a_1) $$

For Associativity I tried showing $3$ transformations are associative i.e $$((Λ_1 a_1) (Λ_2 a_2))(Λ_3 a_3) = (Λ_1 a_1)((Λ_2 a_2)(Λ_3 a_3))$$

I got that this isn't associative but I thought Poincare Transformations formed a group and hence should be associative.

**Edit**

I got that $$(Λ_2 Λ_1 Λ_3 , Λ_2 Λ_1 a_3 + Λ_2a_1+a_2)$$

which is not the same as

$$(Λ_1 Λ_3 Λ_2 , Λ_3 Λ_2 a_1 + Λ_3a_1+a_3)$$

Can someone please provide assistance with this question

Comment: It should be associative, so we can't answer this question unless you tell us why you got that it wasn't.

Comment: @knzhou see me edit as to why I didn't get associativity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The group action of the Poincaré group is given by $$(\Lambda_1;a_1)*(\Lambda_2;a_2)=(\Lambda_1\Lambda_2; a_1 + \Lambda_1 a_2).$$ Thus, we find that \begin{align}\left( (\Lambda_1;a_1)*(\Lambda_2;a_2)\right) * (\Lambda_3;a_3) &= (\Lambda_1\Lambda_2; a_1 + \Lambda_1 a_2) * (\Lambda_3;a_3) \\ &= (\Lambda_1\Lambda_2\Lambda_3; [a_1 + \Lambda_1 a_2] + [\Lambda_1\Lambda_2] a_3) \end{align} on the one hand and \begin{align}(\Lambda_1;a_1)*((\Lambda_2;a_2) * (\Lambda_3;a_3)) &= (\Lambda_1;a_1)*(\Lambda_2\Lambda_3; a_2 + \Lambda_2 a_3) \\ &= (\Lambda_1\Lambda_2\Lambda_3; a_1 + \Lambda_1 [a_2 + \Lambda_2 a_3]) \end{align} on the other. As you can see the multiplication $*$ is indeed associative. I hope this could help you.

Cheers!

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks for explaining this.